# why do I get System.OutOfMemoryException even when there is about 700Mb of RAM free?

Tags: c#, winforms, out-of-memory

I was running some test, to see the how my logging would perform is instead of doing `File.AppendAllText` I would first write to a memory stream and then copy to file. So, just to see how fast memory operation is I did this..

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var memFile = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var bw = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(memFile))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Int32.MaxValue; i++)
                {
                    bw.Write(i.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                bw.Flush();
            }
            memFile.CopyTo(new System.IO.FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine("C", "memWriteWithBinaryTest.log"), System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
        }
    }
```

When `i` reached `25413324` I got a `Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.` even though my [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) says I have about 700Mb of free ram???

Here are the screen shots (just in case)

Process Explorer
[image]

Here's the winform

[image]

**EDIT :** For the sake of more objects being created on heap, I rewrote the `bw.write` to this

```
bw.Write(i);
```

Comment: As per answer, the `BinaryWriter` does not write out the string representation of the number. It will write the byte representation. Maybe you want the latter, but from the original code it does not appear so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, you run out of memory because you accumulate data in the `MemoryStream`, instead of writing it directly to the `FileStream`. Use the `FileStream` directly and you won't need much RAM at all (but you will have to keep the file open).

The amount of physical memory unused is not directly relevant to this exception, as strange as that might sound.

What matters is:

- that you have a contiguous chunk of memory available in the process' *virtual address space*
- that the system commit does not exceed the total RAM size + page file size

When you ask the Windows memory manager to allocate you some RAM, it needs to check not how much is *available*, but how much it has *promised* to make available to every other process. Such promising is done through commits. To *commit* some memory means that the memory manager offered you a guarantee that it *will* be available when you finally make use of it.

So, it can be that the physical RAM is completely used up, but your allocation request still succeeds. Why? Because there is lots of space available in the page file. When you actually start using the RAM you got through such an allocation, the memory manager will just simply page out something else. So 0 physical RAM != allocations will fail.

The opposite can happen too; an allocation can fail despite having some unused physical RAM. Your process sees memory through the so-called *virtual address space*. When your process reads memory at address `0x12340000`, that's a virtual address. It might map to RAM at `0x78650000`, or at `0x000000AB12340000` (running a 32-bit process on a 64-bit OS), it might point to something that only exists in the page file, or it might not even point at anything at all.

When you want to allocate a block of memory with contiguous addresses, it's in this virtual address space that the RAM needs to be contiguous. For a 32-bit process, you only get 2GB or 3GB of usable address space, so it's not too hard to use it up in such a way that no contiguous chunk of a sufficient size exists, despite there being both free physical RAM and enough total unused virtual address space.

Answer (score 3):

This can be caused by memory fragmentation.

Large objects go onto the large object heap and they don't get moved around to make room for things. This can cause fragmentation where you have gaps in the available memory, which can cause out-of-memory when you try to allocate an object larger than any of the blocks of available memory.

[See here for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx).

Any object larger than 85,000 bytes will be placed on the large object heap, except for arrays of doubles for which the threshold is just 1000 doubles (or 8000 bytes).

Also note that 32-bit .Net programs are limited to a maximum of 2GB per object and somewhat less than 4GB overall (perhaps as low as 3GB depending on the OS).

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using a `BinaryWriter` to write text to a file. Use a `TextWriter` instead.

Now you are using:

`for (int i = 0; i < Int32.MaxValue; i++)`

This will write at least 3 bytes per write (number representation and newline). Times that by `Int32.MaxValue` and you need at least 6GB of memory already seeing that you are writing it to a `MemoryStream`.

Looking further at your code, you are going to write the `MemoryStream` to a file in any way. So you can simply do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
  File.AppendAllText("filename.log", i.ToString() + Environment.Newline);
}
```

or write to an open `TextWriter`:

```
TextWriter writer = File.AppendText("filename.log");

for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
  writer.WriteLine(i);
}
```

If you want some memory buffer, which IMO is a bad idea for logging as you will lose the last bit of the writes during a crash, you can using the following the create the `TextWriter`:

```
StreamWriter(string path, bool append, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize)
```

and pass a 'biggish' number for `bufferSize`. The default is `1024`.

To answer the question, you get an out of memory exception due to the `MemoryStream` resizing and at some point it gets to big to fit into memory (which was discussed in another answer).

Comment: Well not exactly a question for logging, I know about Logger.Net etc, but this case was just a simple log, also I needed to know how much performance would be improved (meaning how much less time would be spend) if I first write to memory and then to file.