# Why does this dotnet process throws OutOfMemoryException in docker when there should be plenty available?

Tags: .net, docker, out-of-memory

This code:

```
try
{
    var mem = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 1024];
    Console.WriteLine($"allocated {mem.Length} bytes");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

throws an exception when run in docker using server mode GC even with 5GB memory limit:

```
docker run --memory=5gb -e DOTNET_gcServer=1 memtest
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in /src/memtest/Program.cs:line 10
```

however with workstation mode GC it runs successfully with only 2GB

```
docker run --memory=2gb -e DOTNET_gcServer=0 memtest
allocated 1073741824 bytes
```

what's going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OutOfMemoryException when a lot of memory is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247118/outofmemoryexception-when-a-lot-of-memory-is-available)